# Deploying a WebApp using Glassfish and IntelliJ

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm starting out learning to build a Java EE Web App and following a tutorial which uses Eclipse though I use IntelliJ.

I've build the basic structure and can run the Glassfish server successfully so I see the welcome page at localhost:8080

I'm having some trouble seeing my servlet output displayed however as I get a 404.

When I go to http://localhost:8080/web1_war_exploded/ then I see the output from the index.jsp file

What I want to see is the HTML output from my AddPassenger class when I visit:
http://localhost:8080/web1/AddPassenger.  Instead I get a 404:

[image]

I think I've configured everything as per IntelliJ's own instructions and have created a .war and a Manifest.  I'm just unclear how to deploy and see my AddPassenger servlet which is simply:

```
@WebServlet(name = "/AddPassenger")
public class AddPassenger extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public AddPassenger(){
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("<h2>Welcome to World Adventures Airlines!</h2>");
    out.println("</html>");
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}
```

}

This is my project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `@WebServlet(name = "/AddPassenger")` to `@WebServlet(value = "/AddPassenger")`. In this case it should work on  http://localhost:8080/web1_war_exploded/AddPassenger.

Also using annotations no need to declare servlets in web.xml. And make sure that your glassfish version supports servlet 3.0.

To change path of url from `/web1_war_exploded/` to `/web1/` go to the File->Project Structure and change output dir:
[image]

Comment: thank you, doing as you state does serve the correct page.  However, I'm still unclear why I cannot deploy the .war so I can navigate to the url: localhost:8080/web1/AddPassenger